# Regex to validate input string

Tags: java, regex

I need to have validate input string if they qualify the following format.

```
[composite={key1: value1, key2:value2....., keyn:valuen }]
```

will this regex be okay. Not a regex expert.

```
\[composite\s*=\s*{(.*?)}\]
```

Comment: Escape the `{`and its matching `}` as it has a meaning in regex to represent a quantifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern almost looks correct, except that braces are regex metacharacters and also need to be escaped:

```
String input = "[composite={key1: value1, key2:value2}]";
String pattern = "\\[composite\\s*=\\s*\\{\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*:\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*(?:,\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*:\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*)*\\}\\]";
if (input.matches(pattern)) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

I also modified your pattern to check for comma separated key value pairs, with optional whitespace.  Here is a list of inputs which are valid:

```
[composite={key1: value1}]
[composite={key1: value1 , key2 : value2}]
[composite={key1: value1 , k:v   , key:value, abc:123 }]
```

Note that if you could validate the bracketed content using a JSON parser, this would probably be preferable over a regex.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: instead of (.*?) is it possible to make the regex which says only key:value pairs are accepted ? If yes how that will look ?

Comment: You should not reinforce the erroneous belief that expressions like this one can be verified with a simple regex unless the OP makes explicit assertions about the possible values for valueN.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar I updated my regex to check for one or more key values pairs.

Comment: @laune Using the term "erroneous" to describe my answer is...erroneous.  We don't what level of validation the OP needs.  The bracketed portion looks like JSON content and a parser might be used to handle it.

Comment: It seems quite unrealistic to assume that values cannot be quoted strings with arbitrary content, and if it really is JSON, then it's going to be recursive... Note that I have qualified "erroneous" by adding "unless...".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can we not just have empty one as valid. Than it will be awesome sir

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Updated to require at least one key value pair.